# What are common functions GIS web app should have?

Tags: web-mapping

I'm a programmer making his first steps in the GIS world. In order to get to know this world I wrote some map based apps using WMS / OSM , OpenLayers and MS-SQL (non spatial).
Now I want to put it all together and do some more advanced coding (adding caching capabilities for example , thematic map...)

What are the most common functions in your opinion a GIS app should have ?

I get the obvious are measuring (line and area) probably something related to features info ... But beside that I have no idea what else.

I would like to use your experience for making a base app that will answer most basic GIS requirements (and will put together all the technologies I chose to practice with)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every application is different based on the end users needs, however, I think at a basic level, most applications have:

- Search
- Identify
- Some variation of a Table of Contents/Legend/Selectable Layers or basemaps

But like I said, its best to figure out what the maps purpose is and design the elements around the end goal. Simply plugging in a bunch of features just because they're popular isn't best practice, IMO.